# Setting a dynamic effect to a UIElement.Effect

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, animation, silverlight-4.0

We are using a third party that has some shapes and when one of them are invalid I would like to make it glow. For the moment the only way I make it works is with a `DropShadowEffect`.

```
 myShape.Effect = new DropShadowEffect { BlurRadius = 120, Color = Color.FromArgb(220, 255, 0, 0), Direction = 0, ShadowDepth = 0 };
```

Unfortunately, this is not animated. I know that we can do some animation with VisualState, but I cannot see a way to use it with the UIElement.Effect.

How can I make this glowing effect in Silverlight if I do not have control of the canvas where the shapes are drawn, neither the shape itself since it's a third party?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can have animation now but it works at 90%

I set the effect like previously:

myShape.Effect = new DropShadowEffect { BlurRadius = 500, Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0), Direction = 0, ShadowDepth = 10, Opacity=100};

Then I create a Storyboard and add it:

```
var shadowExpand = new DoubleAnimation();
shadowExpand.From = 1;
shadowExpand.To = 0;
shadowExpand.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000));
shadowExpand.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
shadowExpand.AutoReverse = true;
Storyboard.SetTarget(shadowExpand, addFlowShape);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(shadowExpand, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Opacity)"));
var stb = new Storyboard();
stb.Children.Add(shadowExpand);
```

<strike>The problem is that I see it doing nothing for 1999ms and then flick really fast from 100 to 0 without going gradually.</strike>

Any body can make it smoother?

I had to put 1 not 100 for opacity. Resolved thank you all.